# If T is a Consistent estimator of $\theta$ then $T^3$ is consistent estimator of $\theta^3$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

If T is a Consistent estimator of $\theta$ then $T^3$ is a consistent estimator of $\theta^3$.

Can anyone tell me in a single line what's the logic behind this? I am familiar with invariance property of MLE where $T$ is MLE of $\theta$ and $T^2$ will be MLE of $\theta ^2$ and we know that all MLE's are consistent. If there is some other logic please do tell me I might ve skipped that portion. I want to study that.

Comment: Just the usual $a_n\to a$ then $a_n^3\to a^3$, modified for plim.

Comment: See statement no 2 [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem).

Comment: @StubbornAtom Bhai you are life saver.